# Export Excel with Laravel, VueJS and Inertiajs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to build and application on `Laravel`, `VueJS` and `inertiajs`.

I'm using `maatwebsite/excel` to export my data into excel format.

I've a vue component which has a normal `HTML` form

**home.vue**

```
<form action="/project-profile" target="_blank" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf.content" />
    <input type="hidden" name="slug" :value="JSON.stringify(generalDetails.slug)" />
    <button class="font-medium tracking-wide">Download Profile</button>
</form>
```

And on mounted method I'm just placing my `csrf` token.

```
mounted() {
    this.csrf = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
}
```

In `Laravel` part I made a route in `web.php` file

```
Route::post('project-profile','ProjectProfileExportController@ProjectProfile');
```

Whenever I try to export or submit the form, I get `page expired` error, I followed few guide and it says there is issue with `csrf_token` but while inspecting the form I can see `token` is placed appropriately.

I tried doing the same by making this as api, `api.php`:

```
Route::post('project-profile', 'ProjectProfileExportController@ProjectProfile');
```

But this thing also not work as expected.

[Screenshot of page expired screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP2jS.png)

[Screenshot of inspect form element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO6VR.png)

Any better approach is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creator of Inertia.js here.

So, [we recommend](https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection) not manually sending the `csrf` token on each request like this.

A better approach is to use the CSRF functionality already built into axios for this. Axios is the HTTP library that Inertia uses under the hood.

Axios automatically checks for the existence of an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. If it's present, it will then include the token in an `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header for any requests it makes.

The easiest way to implement this is using server-side middleware. Simply include the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie on each response, and then verify the token using the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header sent in the requests from axios.

Some frameworks, such as Laravel, do this automatically, meaning there is no configuration required. So, I'd recommend removing the `csrf-token` meta tag from your template, and removing the `_token` from your requests. That should take care of your issues.

That all said, keep in mind that you will not be able to download an Excel file from an Inertia request. All Inertia requests MUST return a valid Inertia response. You can use `window.open` for this. Something like this:

```js
window.open(`/url/to/excel/download?slug=${generalDetails.}`, '_blank')
```